# Just got an "your question (from 7 years ago) is closed as duplicate of a question (17h ago)" - what is this policy?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Just for reference I'm talking about: [Multiuser - can process of background user kept running?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82930/multiuser-can-process-of-background-user-kept-running?noredirect=1#comment520558_82930)
Don't judge - not my smartest one, but back then was the first time about fast user switching.

I'm all for clearing up the answers so the best are top. And there is definitely a point how valuable 7 year old computing answers are to questions from today.

OTOH it bothers me to get contacted about a 7 year old question which has a good answer.

I was  curious about how the better answers looks  and - while it's an OK answer - I don't think it  better than the accepted one.

It  looks a bit odd that an author of an answer of a current question goes back and makes an old question a duplicate of the one he just answered and not mark the new ones duplicates.

For all I care, my question could have been deleted once I accepted the answer. I'm more interested in the policy.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for asking. Closing can take a while to get right. I. Your case, I don’t see much harm if any closing to new answers nor in the close direction - sometimes it’s better to close an old post to a new one.

However, I don’t see these as duplicates and have linked then and reversed the close. Let’s see what others think. It might still be closed in one direction or another, but I wanted to leave both linked for a short time as people hop in to meta to see what the consensus is.

Answer (score 2):

**It was closed in the wrong direction**

I read, and re-read both questions/answers several times.  Here are my conclusions:

- Both questions are about processes running in the background of other users accounts
- Both used Fast User Switching to go between the accounts
- The original answer contained more explanation and detail
- **Most importantly, the original answer is still relevant.**

For the record, I am for closing toward a *better* answer regardless of date.  However, closing an existing, up voted and answer accepted question towards a newer one should be done when conditions change (i.e. in Catalina all processes are paused ← this is hypothetical and not real).  When this happens an small edit should be made to the original pointing to the new answer.